# Compare the different ways to pass argument in Python constructor

Tags: python, constructor, arguments

For creating new object in Python Class, there's several ways to pass in args according to my research.

`name: str = None`

`name: Optional[str] = None`

`**kwargs`

I feel the effect is pretty much the same? Even if I do `name: str = 'John'`, I could still skip passing in this arg, but object will still have `John` as age default.

So I'm curious what's their diff? Maybe they have huge diff in other scenarios

Comment: note new style syntax for optional is `str | None` (also a bit shorter)

Comment: yeah, but then how's the `Optional` one is diff from the first way?

Comment: the syntax for first one, outside of class makes my IDE complain. still runs the same though.

Answer (score 0):

So to clarify. What you posted in not "passing in" args but setting defaults to parameters.

Ignoring **kwargs since that is completely separate from the other two.
There really is no difference.

If you open PyCharm and do these two functions...

```
def test(name: str = None):
    pass

def test2(name: Optional[str] = None):
    pass
```

If you hover over the parameters pycharm shows that both equal "str | None".

The type hint `Optional` does have some use with type checking tools like mypy as it tells the checker more clearly what it is you are wanting to do but other than that to python they are identical.